# Как перекрыть одно событие другим

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт для блоков div: при наведении на блок1 в соседнем блоке2 отображается скрытый блок, аналогично при наведении блок2 в первом блоке1 появляется блок, который скрыт. Вопрос, как сделать так, что бы при случайном наведении мыши вскользь по обеим блокам сценарий выполнялся только для последнего на который навелась мышь, т.е. предыдущая анимация закончилась (а то они маргают вместе) и как написать, что бы при многократном быстром наведении на блок он не моргал сто раз, а методы fadeIn() и fadeOut прервались для всех кроме последнего наведения. Вопроса по сути два, но в природе своей схожи и решение возможно есть одно. Спасибо, извините если немного запутанно обьяснил.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#us_disposition").hover(
     function(){
         $("#fast_photo_back").fadeIn();
     },
     function() {
        $("#fast_photo_back").fadeOut();
    }
    )
    
    $("#fast_photo").hover(
     function(){
         $("#us_disposition_back").fadeIn();
     },
     function() {
        $("#us_disposition_back").fadeOut();
    }
    )
    
    
})
```

Comment: дайте пример Вашей css

Comment: это называется debounce